# Удаление всего связанного с python

Tags: python, macos

Хочу удалить все, что связано с `python`, чтобы заново самому поставить и настроить. Установлены `pip`, `virtualenv`. Мне нужно, чтобы все было чисто, как при новой *OS X El Capitano* (только `python2.7`).

Проблема решилась. В терминале запустил `brew doctor`, он вывел файлы которые нужно удалить.

Comment: *"Чтобы всё было чисто"*, вы можете создать virtualenv, в котором системные библиотеки недоступны (поведение по умолчанию), ничего не удаляя.

Comment: переустанови винду :D

Comment: так у меня Мак )) у меня virtualenv стоит, что то нахимичил, теперь хочу все удалить бесследно и заново поставить.